# Loop gradient effect on existing button

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a button that is already exist :

```
<div class="button-loader locationButton brandBlue fontMediumTitle " id="locationButton"></div>
```

I would like to be able to add a class `button-loader` , to this button ***or any other button***, and

1. keep it's current background color
2. animate from left to right **and back, in a loop** - so that I start with the *original* color and change its `opacity` from left to right and back to original.(say it become 0.5 in opacity from left, and back to 1.0 from right)

```
.button-loader {     
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;

   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.95), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0));
   background-size: 200% 100%;
   background-position: right bottom;
   transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
 }

 .button-loader:hover {
   background-position: left bottom;
 }
```

Current code *will not loop forever* and *will not keep the original color before animation begin(its already gradient)*

Comment: You can you Keyframes for animating infinitely

Comment: Can you explain ?

Comment: A keyframe is basically used for pure animation, So you can use them to change opacity values on hover or even do much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the gradient on a pseudo element instead where you can easily keep the initial background color:

```css
.button-loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.button-loader:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.95) 40% 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0));
  background-size:600% 100%;
  background-position:right;
  transition:1s all;
}

.button-loader:hover:before {
  background-position:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-loader" style="background:blue;"></div>
<div class="button-loader" style="background:red;"></div>

<div class="button-loader" style="background:linear-gradient(red,purple);"></div>
```

For an infinite animation, you can replace transition with animation:

```css
.button-loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.button-loader:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.95) 45% 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0));
  background-size:600% 100%;
  background-position:right;
  animation:change 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes change {
to {
  background-position:left;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="button-loader" style="background:blue;"></div>
<div class="button-loader" style="background:red;"></div>
<div class="button-loader" style="background:linear-gradient(red,purple);"></div>
```

You can also animate translate for better performance:

```css
.button-loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.button-loader:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:600%;
  bottom:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.95) 45% 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0));
  animation:change 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes change {
to {
  transform:translate(84%);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="button-loader" style="background:blue;"></div>
<div class="button-loader" style="background:red;"></div>
<div class="button-loader" style="background:linear-gradient(red,purple);"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but for infinite animation how do I start and stop it ? (even using javascript?)

Comment: @Curnelious when and how you want to start and stop it?

Comment: say on a click or something, from my JS

Comment: @Curnelious you can consider this property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state